# Proper way to find out which Tab of QTabWidget is currently selected

Tags: c++, qt

I have a [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html) with several tabs, every tab containing a QTableWidget with numbers. Outside of this QTabWidget, I have one button. When the button is pressed, the currently selected widget should be processed. The QTableWidgets are identical in their structure, they just display numbers, and if I have a pointer to one of these widgets, I cannot deduce which tab it came from.

A simple method to identify which widget is currently selected is to call `currentIndex()`. But this will break when I reorder the tabs in the designer and is probably not working with movable tabs.

Another way is to use `currentIndex()` and `tabText(int index)`. Like this I have a stable way to find out which tab is currently selected. The disadvantage  of this is that I am then dependent on having unique tab texts, and I in general don't like to rely on a UI property to implement functionality.

My solution for now is to give every Widget a different accessible name that I can then read out like this:

```
  QWidget* widget = tabWidget->currentWidget();
  QString* name = widget->accessibleName();
```

This works, but I wonder if there is a better solution, something like the `Qt::UserRole` that can be assigned to any cell in a [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html).

Comment: `currentIndex()` does provide a unique way of identifying the tabs. It will not break with movable tabs either: `currentWidget()` is simply the widget visible on the current tab. So if you have 10 tabs, you are viewing the 6th tab, the `currentIndex()` will return `5` and `currentWidget()` will give you the widget on the current tab. Next, say you move the 3rd tab to the 9th position. Then the `currentIndex()` will return `4` and `currentWidget()` will return the same widget as before.

Comment: @Marcus, thanks for the input and the clarification regarding the movable tabs. However, the logic does break if I change the tabs in Qt Designer. Let's say I have code `if (index == 0) then doA(); else if (index == 1) then doB();` and Tabs labelled 'TabA' and 'TabB'. Now all is working fine, doA is executed if TabA is active and doB if TabB is active. If I now decide that TabB should be before TabA and change that in QDesigner, then TabB has index 0, TabA has index 1. doB() is then executed if I'm on TabA and doA() is executed if I'm on TabB...

Comment: Ah.. How about this instead: Instead of depending on names for the tabs, just name the widgets themselves? You can use `objectName()` and `setObjectName( QString )` for the widgets. However, you'll still have to name them uniquely.

Comment: Hm, good idea. Thanks! That's better than using the accessibleName. I'll accept this as an answer.